# TFRecords encoded as BytesList with bytes but only sometimes decodes from record as int64 throwing InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a numpy arrays of dtype int32 being encoded by ndarray.tostring() then as a _bytes_feature into seperate TFRecord files, like so:

```
_bytes_feature = lambda string: tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[string]))
labels = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
labels_raw = labels.tostring()
assert isinstance(labels_raw, bytes)
features = {"labels": _bytes_feature(labels_raw)}
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(record_path + sound_name + "_{}.tfrecords".format(i)) as writer:
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

I read them out of the files using

```
def parser(serialized_example):
    features_description = {'labels': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features_description)
    labels = tf.decode_raw(features['labels'], tf.int32)
    return labels

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(list_of_tfrecords_files)
dataset = dataset.map(parser)
```

This process works seamlessly for roughly 30K different labels arrays however on around 500 of those arrays:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Key: labels.  Data types don't match. Data type: int64 but expected type: string
 [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample}} = ParseSingleExample[Tdense=[DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING], dense_keys=["image/height", "image/mfcc", "image/width", "labels"], dense_shapes=[[], [], [], []], num_sparse=0, sparse_keys=[], sparse_types=[]](arg0, ParseSingleExample/Const, ParseSingleExample/Const_1, ParseSingleExample/Const, ParseSingleExample/Const_1)]]
 [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,?,?,1], [?,80]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]
```

I've checked which label arrays this happens on and there doesn't seem to be any discernible difference from those with which the process works.

```
>>> tf.__version__
'1.12.0'
```

Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out to be a somewhat human error. I was continually over-writting the tfrecord files as I learnt about creating them, or so I thought. I had previously writen the labels out as an int64 list and these files weren't getting overwritten for some reason. Hence why they were still int64 when they were called by the parser. After deleting all the records entirely and rerunning the creation and parsing of said files, the process ran without a hitch.